# Method Returning Zero in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm trying to write a simple calculator in C# where a user inputs their weight and bodyfat percentage and the program tells them their Lean Body Mass. When debugging it always seems to say their lean body mass is the same as their weight leading me to believe that the getBodyfatAmount is returning 0.

```
namespace Fitness_Calcualtors
{
    public partial class Lean_Body_Mass : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        int bodyWeight, bodyFatPercentage, leanBodyMass, bodyFatAmount;

        public Lean_Body_Mass()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private int getBodyfatAmount()
        {
            bodyFatAmount = ((bodyFatPercentage / 100) * bodyWeight);
            return bodyFatAmount;
        }

        private void convertInput()
        {
            bodyWeight = Convert.ToInt32(bodyweightTextBox.Text);
            bodyFatPercentage = Convert.ToInt32(bodyFatTextBox.Text);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                if (kilogramsRadioButton.IsChecked ==true)
                {
                    convertInput();
                    getBodyfatAmount();

                    leanBodyMass = (bodyWeight - bodyFatAmount);
                    resultTextBox.Text = leanBodyMass.ToString() + " Kilos";
                }
                else if (poundsRadioButton.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    convertInput();
                    getBodyfatAmount();

                    leanBodyMass = (bodyWeight - bodyFatAmount);
                    resultTextBox.Text = leanBodyMass.ToString() + " Lbs";
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the values entered in `bodyweightTextBox` and `bodyFatTextBox` when `getBodyfatAmount()` returns `0`?

Comment: You should consider making these: `int bodyWeight, bodyFatPercentage, leanBodyMass, bodyFatAmount;` doubles instead of ints

Comment: My guess is that because you're dividing an int that is probably less than 100, when it is truncating the decimal it is leaving 0. try changing all your variables to double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're performing integer division in this line:

```
((bodyFatPercentage / 100) * bodyWeight);
```

Because (bodyFatPercentage / 100) is less than 1, it is automatically truncated to 0, and so the whole function returns 0.

You could instead use:

```
(int)((bodyFatPercentage / 100.0) * bodyWeight);
```

Alternatives include

```
(int)Math.Round((bodyFatPercentage / 100.0) * bodyWeight);
bodyFatPercentage * bodyWeight / 100
```

or simply returning a floating point value.

Personally, I'd return a floating point value. As a general rule of thumb, don't give away precision until you need to display it (and if you want a less precise display). Otherwise, you can get compounding rounding errors, which is, essentially, what happened here.

Comment: this may not help as the left type determines the type of the operator IIRC.

Comment: The method is returning `int`, although the point you made about integer division is correct, but this will not fix the issue, the method's return type should be a type supporting floating point numbers.

Comment: No, a widening conversion will be performed. The left type doesn't determine it, what determines it is whichever type holds more data.

Comment: @Habib it will fix the issue, because he's multiplying by `bodyWeight` afterwards. Integer truncation will still happen, but to what I assume is the place he wants, as opposed to losing data in the middle of the process.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly your values are too small and the results are like `0.something`, and `int` cannot hold `.`(decimal) containing values so it rounds off the value to **ZERO**. I suggest you to use `double` to return the value.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone else does give you the programming solution of casting to a float or double first, but there is another solution from your 3rd grade math class. The multiplication and division is transitive.

```
bodyFatAmount = ((bodyFatPercentage * bodyWeight) / 100);
```

Now by multiplying first you get a number larger than 100 and don't get the truncation issue, once you divide it will still give you the correct percentage value.

Answer (score 1):

assuming, bodyFatPercentage is a value between 0 and 100,
`(bodyFatPercentage / 100)` will return 0. Why?
Because you are dividing integers.
Change your code to use double values and you are on the right track.
`((double)bodyFatPercentage / 100)`

If your result is of type int, you may have to cast or better `Math.Round` the result back to int.

Comment: useful tip: set a breakpoint on your method (click on the left bar or press F9) and hover your mouse over your variables. You can also select a whole expression and hover or press SHIFT+F9 to see its value.

Answer (score 1):

Try the modifications below, your problems are to do with performing non-integer maths with integers.  I've also tidied up some of the code to be more readable and closer to the Microsoft coding standards, removed excessive brackets, removed excessive private variables, etc.:

```
public partial class LeanBodyMass : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private decimal bodyWeight;
    private decimal bodyFatPercentage;

    public LeanBodyMass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private decimal GetBodyFatAmount()
    {
        return bodyFatPercentage / 100m * bodyWeight;
    }

    private void ConvertInput()
    {
        bodyWeight = Convert.Decimal(bodyweightTextBox.Text);
        bodyFatPercentage = Convert.Decimal(bodyFatTextBox.Text);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ConvertInput();
        this.GetBodyFatAmount();

        decimal leanBodyMass = bodyWeight - bodyFatAmount;

        if (kilogramsRadioButton.IsChecked ==true)
        {
            resultTextBox.Text = string.Format("{0} Kilos", leanBodyMass);
        }
        else if (poundsRadioButton.IsChecked == true)
        {
            resultTextBox.Text = string.Format("{0} Lbs", leanBodyMass);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should step through with a debugger in order to confirm the exact source of the problem.

However, I expect the problem is due to rounding. When working with division it is best to use a type that supports decimal places.

Try this:

```
bodyFatAmount = (int)((bodyFatPercentage / 100f) * bodyWeight);
```

Basically, `bodyFatPercentage / 100` is always going to result in `0.xx` (mathematically) but because you are using `int` types (that don't support decimal places) it will round the value to `0`. by using `100f` instead, you are declaring one of the types as float (which does support decimal places), thus the result will keep the decimal precision (`0.xx`) this will then be multiplied by `bodyWeight` and again result in a float value (maintaining decimal places), finally your overall result can then be cast back to an `int`. This will again do the round, but by then you will have a more accurate result, for example, `(int)63.22` -> `63`

---

On a side note, it is very strange for functions to set global variables like that, and then return the value too. Just my thoughts thoughts...